# ASP.NET Core MVC : how to store iprogress result

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, iprogress

I am trying to implement a "real time" progress bar that displays the progress of an async task (blob upload). The task is executed in a service (of a class library), which itself is called by a web controller.

Service method:

```
public async Task UploadFileToBlob(MemoryStream stream, string path, HttpContext context)
{
    IProgress<StorageProgress> progressHandler = new Progress<StorageProgress>(
    progress => context.Session.SetString("UploadBytesTransferred", progress.BytesTransferred.ToString());
        
    CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlockBlob();

    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream, default(AccessCondition), requestOptions, default(OperationContext), progressHandler, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
}
```

The controller call:

```
await _blobService.UploadFileToBlob(memoryStream, azureStoragePath, HttpContext);
```

The progress should later be retrieved by another controller action like here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFileUploadProgress()
{
    long progress = 0;
    var sessionEntry = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UploadBytesTransferredPercent");

    if (sessionEntry != null)
        progress = Convert.ToInt64(sessionEntry);

    return Json(progress);
}
```

My first try, as shown in the code, was to store the progress in a session variable, but it doesn't work and is probably not recommended. Is there a better and reliable way to get at the progress of the task? Or is something wrong with the code?

Comment: You could use SignalR to send progress to the client. See [Progress report using SignalR and IProgress interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584754/progress-report-using-signalr-and-iprogress-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MemoryCache to store the upload progress (it is not blocked by upload request). Probably not best practice, but sufficient for my needs.

```
public async Task UploadFileToBlob(MemoryStream stream, string path, IMemoryCache cache)
{      
    IProgress<StorageProgress> progressHandler = new Progress<StorageProgress>(
        progress => cache.Set("UploadBytesTransferred", progress.BytesTransferred)
    ));
        
    var blob = GetBlockBlob(path);

    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream, default(AccessCondition), requestOptions, default(OperationContext), progressHandler, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
}
```